# What's the `dev channel release` of install Dart SDK?

Tags: dart

I am reading [dart dev](https://dart.dev/get-dart):

there are:

```
 brew tap dart-lang/dart
 brew install dart

**To install a dev channel release, use --devel:**

 brew install dart --devel
```

What's the difference between `brew install dart` and `brew install dart --devel`?

there say `install a dev channel release` , what's the meaning of `dev channel release` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart dev releases are development snapshots towards the next Dart release, as opposed to stable releases (which you normally want to use).

For instance, the latest stable release right now is Dart `2.7`. The latest dev release is `2.8.0-dev.0.0`, which is [less](https://semver.org/) than the upcoming `2.8` stable release. Dev releases are made regularly (~weekly) from the latest source code to help test Dart continuously. You normally want to use the stable releases. You may want to use a dev release temporarily if you want to try out a new feature or if there is a bug fix you need.

There is [more information](https://dart.dev/get-dart#about-release-channels-and-version-strings) at the bottom of the download page.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install dart` mean you install Dart with latest stable version.

and the `brew install dart --devel` mean you install the latest development version.

You can see the [Dart version options of Windows](https://gekorm.com/dart-windows/):

there have choices: `GET DART (64-BIT WINDOWS, STABLE)` and `GET DART (64-BIT WINDOWS, DEV)`, that's the meaning.